# The "paypal for digital goods plugin" for wordpress redirects to blank confirmation page

Tags: wordpress, paypal, payment

I have set up a sandbox account and have selected option 2 to get my api credentials giving me my merchants user name, password and signature. I have uploaded my wordpress site to a sub domain of the email address I used to registered with Paypal. I have installed the plugin...

https://wordpress.org/plugins/paypal-for-digital-goods/

activated it and entered the details found on the option 2 page as well as setting the check box to work with the sandbox account. I then added a purchase button to one of the pages on the website.

When I click the purchase button it allows me to login and shows me the correct payment, allows me to accept the payment and then sends me back to the plugin page...

http://xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxx.com/?page_id=2593?step=confirm&token=EC-1K141602YT0994237&PayerID=62CA9BAZ6BYN4

BUT this page is blank with no information even after viewing source code and no download has been offered.

I'm a bit stuck as I have read quite a few instructions on how this should be done and I seem to have followed all the required steps. So any help would be appreciated.